# Function outside look that requires a list to be generated that will randomly select 4 options

Tags: python-3.x

How to write this pseudo in python:

```
Display ‘ opening box’
Display ‘Item 1 of 4… common Item!’
        ‘Item 2 of 4…rare item!’
        ‘Item 2 of 4…epic item!’
        ‘Item 2 of 4…legendary item!’
```

The items are randomly choosen. When this function is called on in the body, it is meant to generate this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below :

```
import random

items = ['Common Item', 'Rare Item', 'Epic Item', 'Legendary Item']
print("Opening Box\n")
for i in range(1, 5):
    print('Item '+str(i)+' of 4 ----', random.choice(items))
```

Comment: and if i wanted to dusplay it 4 times, everytime open box was selected.

Comment: what do you want to display 4 times ?

Comment: the item just like i showed in the pseudo. to print it out to display 4 items at random from the 4 choices

Comment: Have edited the code..have a look

Comment: yes but its coming out 1 of 4 and after that 3 of 4 and 3 of 4. How can i make it in order from 1 -4 to 4-4?

Comment: Whats random in that then ?Your question say , the list will randomly select 4 items

Comment: the random change is common, rare, epic and legendary.

Comment: check if this answers your question or not ?

Comment: Yes it works well

Comment: You can accept and upvote if this was useful.

Comment: if i wanted to make this a function and call it in the body of the loop as open_box. how would i do so? I am receiving this error <function open_box at 0x037D0C88>